# FileInputStream available method returns 2 when there is only 1 byte in the file

Tags: java, file, inputstream

As said in the title I am trying to read a file byte by byte using a FileInputSteam. My code reads:

```
FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(inFileName);
System.out.println(input.available());
```

My file inFileName contains only the character "±" which should only amount to one byte, however when i run the program, the output is 2.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: BTW, as per javadocs - available - Returns an estimate of the number of remaining bytes that can be read

Comment: Number of characters and number of bytes are two different things. What is the size of file as reported by your OS?

Answer (score 5):

That is a unicode character, which in this case is 2 bytes.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b1/index.htm

Scroll down to the UTF-8 part and you can see the value of each byte.

If your ultimate goal is to get a string from a byte array that is UTF-8, then you can generate a String from bytes using `new String(bytes, "UTF-8");`

It's also possible that this is UTF-16 (which would also be 2 bytes), but that is less common.